# Requery Subform after dynamic SQL is updated.

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic, subforms

I have a small DBase, it coordinates tools in 6 separate shops. 
Selecting the name of the shop you want to look at updates the SQL of the qryInventory
just fine so its looking at the correct table, but I have not been able to get the subform to update.

I've looked all over the next and found several variations of this code, 
but I've not been able to get them to work at all.

Forms.Form_UpdateInventoryForm.Form_Inventory00.Requery

Comment: Just a suggestion, put all the shops in the same table (unless they have drastically different fields) and add a ShopID field. This way, all you would have to do is set shop ID to a parameter value and avoid the dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
[NameOfMainForm].[NameOfSubformControl].Form.Requery
```

If you are running this from the main form, you can use Me instead of  [NameOfMainForm]. Be careful to use the name of the subform control, not the form contained. Form and Requery are just as they stand. Form is a property of the subform control.

More information: http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Thankyou for the link, it looks like an excellend resource.

Comment: Me!Inventory00.Form.Requery is working to the extent it throws no errors, but the test data I put in so I have a visual Q. is telling me the actual data is not changing, even though when I click on the underlying Query it comes up with the correct data set.

Comment: Have you set up link child and master fields? Are you replacing the subform Record Source when the shop is changed? As Jeff O suggests, if all this data was in the same tables, you could use the shop id (either control or field) as the link between form and subform and the subform would automatically update when a new shop was selected.

Comment: I've found the Anwser, if you Query Dynamic sql and reopen subform you'll find a fair number of people have had this problem, it seems that a simple requery does not work here. Access must think, I've polled that Query or something. but we have an anwser.

Comment: Wayne at bytes.com provided this snippet of code that works and deserves due props. TY however for the excellent links I know they are going to be invaluable. BB. 'me.subformname.form.recordsource = queryname

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, including the failure of Requery-ing the subform.

What seems to fix the issue, at least in my case, is clearing the SourceObject property of the subform control in the Parent (master) form and then resetting it.  This assumes Form_Master is set..

```
    Form_Master.SubformQuery.SourceObject = "" 'this is the important part
    Form_Master.SubformQuery.SourceObject = "Query.ListSearchQuery"
```

Note that I am doing an obscure thing, which is using a Query as the Source Object.  This seems to force Access to look at the new sql, even if it has just changed in the referenced query.

Hopefully, this would work in the normal form situation as well.  You could probably generalize it to something like this

```
    Dim sourceReset As String
    Dim Form_Master As Form_Master 

    Set Form_Master = Forms!Master
    sourceReset = Form_Master.SubformControl.SourceObject
    Form_Master.SubformControl.SourceObject = ""  'force reset
    Form_Master.SubformControl.SourceObject = sourceReset
```